# QGIS 3.6.2 with GRASS - Can't find the GRASS command path parameter

Tags: qgis-3, grass-gis

I have QGIS 3.6.2 with GRASS 7.6.1 installed. Following the advise of this post [GRASS Processing not working on QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/304245/grass-processing-not-working-on-qgis) I want to work with GRASS 7.7 but I don't have the parameter to set the path to the GRASS folder as I've seen in some screenshots.

[image: The provider settings on my machine]

How can I change where QGIS looks for GRASS commands folder?

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS 3.x the processing paths and settings for GRASS and other external processing libraries are located in the **Settings** >> **Options** window.

Under the **Advanced** tab on the left you must confirm the 'caution warning'.

The GRASS settings can be found under the **Processing** >> **Configuration** tree